# What exactly is white space?

Tags: website-design, design-principles, terminology, education, white-space

I'm new to web design. I'm studying white space but I haven't found yet a clearer explanation of what space is and when I need to use it.

The tutorial that I've read only said that white space is necesary and I have to use it to focus the attention of users in the UI. I'm not sure in which cases I should use it.

Also, the explanation that I have shows a couple of examples of pages that apply white space well but I still don't know why in that case white space was used and why in another cases  it's not good.

Comment: White space is all the empty areas

Comment: In a nutshell - it allows your page / screen elements to breath and used well can create focus. It isn't specific to web design or even graphic design... I was first taught it at art college for life drawing and still life painting - the space in and around a figure / object is just as important a consideration as the object itself. Rather than looking for a snapshot answer I would invest in your art and design learning - start with Henri de Toulouse-Lautrec who was a highly influential bridge between the two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at any design, be it a website, flyer, brochure, poster, anything on paper or on screen, whitespace is literally what the name says: all the unoccupied space surrounding everything else on the design.

Whitespace does not need to be **white**, it can be black or pretty much any color, the term refers more to that space in a design which is empty of any other graphic elements, like a blank background area.

In a good design, whitespace is many times intentionally manipulated and adjusted to separate between navigation and content, to break actual content into sections, or to direct attention to (or away from) specific elements on the design.

Just a random article that illustrates this:

- https://sympli.io/blog/why-is-whitespace-in-web-design-so-powerful/